# Evaluate the goodness of piecewise linear approximation of a cubic Bézier

Tags: approximation-algorithms

I saw that there are different algorithms for piecewise linear approximation of cubic Bézier curves out there.

Now suppose that these algorithms can be either used interchangeably or that the parameters can be changed.

I'm looking for a method to evaluate the goodness of the approximation in order to accept an algorithm or its parameters values as long as the result is still "good".

For example, given a tolerance one could go along the curve or its approximation and check that the distance between the two is below the tolerance.

Any advice?

Really appreciated

UPDATE:

Below what I've been thinking about so far:

1. A cubic Bézier curve is a parametric one with **t** as parameter. *B(t)* can be split respect to the two coordinates in *x(t)* and *y(t)*.
   **t** belongs to the interval *[0,1]*.
2. The linear approximation produces a set of line segments whose endpoints lie on the curve.
3. Given one of these segments above I can find its gradient *m'*.
4. I can then find the tangent, to the Bézier curve, parallel to the segment that has been considered, i.e. the gradient shall be the same as the one found at the point 3.
5. What I really need is the point of contact between the tangent and the curve. This way the distance "point of contact - approx segment" should represent the maximum distance.
6. To find the point of contact the idea was to calculate $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ then $m=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$=*m'*. This should give **t** relative to the point of contact on the curve.

Does it all make sense?

Of course there are special case to be considered like when the Bézier curve degenerates to a segment.

Comment: you could just take the maximum deviation of the curve from the straight line.

Comment: any reference to see how to achieve that?

Comment: With respect to your point 2, approaches based on curve subdivision will tend to do that, but it isn't necessarily optimal. With respect to Carlo's comment, de Casteljau subdivision and the convex hull property.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to investigate further taking in account your advices.